# ETL Oracle Connection error ORA-01017: invalid username/password;

Tags: oracle, etl

I am testing my oracle connecting on ETL but getting this odd error: 
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; I am 100% sure my credentials are correct, as it works on SQL Developer.

More Details:

```
Error at <Package_name> [Connection manager "OracleSource"]: OCI error encountered. ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap)
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap)
```

Comment: Even though you are 100% the credentials are right, I am inclined to believe Oracle more that you provided the wrong username or password.

Comment: Can I check oracle logs to see what credentials were supplied by ETL?

Comment: I did try in another machine, and got successful connection. Oracle database and ETL are same in both the places, not sure what is messed up in machine1

Comment: make sure you're actually talking to the RIGHT database, make sure your password is entered correctly, they are case sensitive in most newer oracle systems. make sure you're not logging in as SYS

Answer (score 0):

Check the case of the password.  A password with the wrong case may work in some clients but fail in others.

Ancient versions of Oracle SQL Developer may use the case-insensitive Oracle 10g password hash algorithm (3DES?).  If your ETL tool has a more modern Oracle client it will use the case-sensitive 11g (SHA?) or 12c (PBKDF?) hashes.